# python3 exited without any error when use pickle.load()

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pickle

I used `pickle.dump(dic, open(a_dic,'wb'))` to save a Python3 dic in another script, it's 15 MB.
When I used `pickle.load(open(a_dic,'rb'))` to load this dic, my script just stops without any error.

```
print('start to load')
pickle.load(open(a_dic,'rb'))
print('finished')
```

The terminal only output this and exit:

```
start to load
```

Comment: I use pickle.dump() saved lots of variable, but python only exit when load this dic

Answer (score 2):

So there's no way to know if the file has been successfully loaded.

You should change your code to

```
print('start')
with open(a_dic, 'rb') as file:
    try:
        var = pickle.load(file)
    except pickle.PicklingError as exc:
        print('Got pickling error: {0}'.format(exc))
print('finished')
```

You may then add other prints, or just run that code in a debugger to know what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I add try-except, but still only output 'start' and exit.

Comment: Have you run it on a debugger (ie pycharm if you're not familiar with python) ? Have you added a print statement just before and after the pickle statement so you know exactly where it stops ? I guess your file is bad. Also, it's strange that you read the file as binary. What are it's contents ?

Comment: I can load this dic in IDE such as VS code, but when I run it in the terminal as a script, it didn't work...

Comment: So can you post your file content somewhere ? I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be read as binary.

Comment: Checked the file, looks good to me. Also, forget what I said,it should be read binary. In my python 3.7.8 interpreter, it loads without any problem. You said it did work in an IDE. Do you use the same python versions in the IDE and your terminal ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure they are in the same version buddy... Very strange... I never met this problem before

Comment: I closed the terminal and reopen it... it worked...  I still don't know why but really thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What's the content of your dictionary? Pickle is a format that deliberately allows nearly arbitrary code execution. If, for example, the pickle contains an instance of an object of a class defined in module foo, and that module foo executes code like `exit()` when imported, you may just told the interpreter to exit when the pickle is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a dictionary like {1:'a',2:'b'...}. I'm sure it can be load in vs code, but when I load it in a command-line python script, it only run the code before the line I load this dictionary and then, exit... really make me confused.